# Find Files Uploaded in Last 24 Hours using Java Graph SDK

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to be able to find the files uploaded to a microsoft sharepoint site in the last 24h, using the graph-api-sdk.

I have tried many things but nothing seem to work, this seem to be my last attempt.
But i dont understand why it is not working

```
String siteId = "";

OffsetDateTime startTime = OffsetDateTime.now().minusHours(24);
SiteRequestBuilder site = graphClient.sites(siteid);

DriveItemSearchCollectionPage results = site.drive().root()
    .search(
        DriveItemSearchParameterSet.newBuilder()
        .withQ("LastModifiedTime ge "+ startTime)
        .build()
    ).buildRequest().get();

for (DriveItem driveItem : results.getCurrentPage()) {
    System.out.println("----------------> "+driveItem.name);
}
```

The modify time does not solve my issue, it shows the file modify time not the upload.

Test this. Take any complex file, pdf, xls, doc, any complex file, that was modify sometime ago, and upload it.

When it is uploaded the modify time is the same one the file had on your pc, not the upload time to sharepoint

### UPDATE

Taking into consideration i cannot seem to be able to detect the correct upload date.

I was thinking, is is possible for me to do a search for a Yes/No custom column named processed, and find all that have processed as false.

And when i run the process on the file then change the value to true, so that i wont process the same file 2 times?

If so how could i change my query to include this field,

i tried this but it does not seem to work

```
SiteRequestBuilder sitereq = graphClient.sites(siteid);
String webUrl = sitereq.buildRequest().get().webUrl;
String queryString = String.format("isDocument=true AND processed=false AND path: \"%s\" ", webUrl);

LinkedList<SearchRequest> requestsList = new LinkedList<>();
SearchRequest requests = new SearchRequest();

LinkedList<EntityType> entityTypesList = new LinkedList<>();
entityTypesList.add(EntityType.DRIVE_ITEM);
requests.entityTypes = entityTypesList;

LinkedList<SortProperty> sortProperties = new LinkedList<>();
SortProperty sort = new SortProperty();
sort.name = "LastModifiedTime";
sort.isDescending = false;
sortProperties.add(sort);

SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery();
query.queryString = queryString;
requests.query = query;
requests.sortProperties = sortProperties;
requests.size = 500;

requestsList.add(requests);

SearchEntityQueryParameterSet sqp = SearchEntityQueryParameterSet
                .newBuilder()
                .withRequests(requestsList)
                .build();

SearchEntityQueryCollectionRequest searchRequest = graphClient.search().query(sqp).buildRequest();
SearchEntityQueryCollectionPage searchResult = searchRequest.post();
```

Comment: what are you expecting and what are you getting as result ?

Comment: i was expecting the driveItem to collect the id from them and them add a specific tag to them

Comment: did you inspect the content of results ?

Comment: it comes empty, nothing is brougth

Comment: Do you need to search all subfolders or only the root folder?

Comment: @user2250152 i need to search the whole site, root folder and all

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes you code will search only the current folder. So I would recommend to try /search/query [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-5-use-filters-in-search-queries)

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76852680/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: cont' - Now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`/site/drive/root` endpoint doesn't support searching as you expect. Better is to use `/search/query` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-5-use-filters-in-search-queries)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "LastModifiedTime > 2023-08-14 AND isDocument=true AND path:\"https://tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name\""
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

Code for java SDK

```
LinkedList<SearchRequest> requestsList = new LinkedList<SearchRequest>();
SearchRequest requests = new SearchRequest();
LinkedList<EntityType> entityTypesList = new LinkedList<EntityType>();
entityTypesList.add(EntityType.DRIVE_ITEM);
requests.entityTypes = entityTypesList;
SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery();
query.queryString = "LastModifiedTime > 2023-08-10 AND isDocument=true AND path:\"https://tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name\"";
requests.query = query;
requests.from = 0;
requests.size = 500;

requestsList.add(requests);

graphClient.search()
    .query(SearchEntityQueryParameterSet
        .newBuilder()
        .withRequests(requestsList)
        .build())
    .buildRequest()
    .post();
```

Comment: This seems to  help, but for some reason, when i upload a xlsx file it does not bring the file in the result, but another file a txt uploaded at the same time and the same location is found

Comment: @rread It seems to be some service issue on the server side. Are you able to find older xlsx file? I can confirm similar behavior with a xlsx file. The file appears in the result of the search after several minutes in my case.

Comment: it seems my approach is not correct, the modified times does not give me the upload time for the file. If i upload a old file for example, it will search the file for the OS modified time.